# INSERT + SELECT + ON DUPLICATE KEY with column aliases in SELECT clause

Tags: mysql, select, insert, sql-update

I'm hitting a rather surprising roadblock when attempting to chain together INSERT, SELECT and ON DUPLICATE KEY in a query where the SELECT clause has column aliases. For example, consider the following situation:

**Tables**:

```
CREATE TABLE source ( 
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    v INT NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO source (v) VALUES (1), (2), (3);
CREATE TABLE dest (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    v INT NOT NULL
);
```

Suppose I'm trying to fill `dest.v` with the values of `POW(source.v,2)` regardless of if values exist in `dest` already. Naturally, I tried:

```
INSERT INTO dest 
    SELECT id, POW(v, 2) AS p FROM source 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE dest.v=source.p;
```

However, MySQL insists that source.p doesn't exist:

> ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'source.p' in 'field list'

Rather inconveniently, I have to resort to using the slower and more cumbersome query:

```
INSERT INTO dest 
    SELECT * FROM ( 
         SELECT id, POW(v, 2) AS p FROM source 
    ) s
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE dest.v=s.p;
```

which differs very little from the original query, but works. Why is this the case?

Comment: Your alternative code simply adds a new set of records as there is no key field in the select result to make a duplicate key hit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I always write the query a below

```
INSERT INTO dest ( id, v)
SELECT id, POW(v, 2) AS p FROM source 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE dest.v=VALUES(v);
```

VALUES() avoid writing same expression again. Always try to specify the columns name you are inserting, just in case you add a new column to the table in some time future

Comment: It seems that `UPDATE dest.v=VALUES(v);` set `dest.v` to itself. Maybe I should clarify: that the query needs to change the values in `dest` if the values in `source` change. For example, if I run `UPDATE source SET v=v*2;`, `SELECT v FROM dest WHERE id=3` should yield 36 in this scenario.

Comment: values(v) means the value you have formulated in the insert will be used. Please read more in the manual : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: Oh true! Sorry, I misunderstood; I misinterpreted the function of `VALUES`.

Answer (score 0):

The alias for the function is just evaluated by mysql for direct use. An alternative query which is a bit less bad, might be:

```
INSERT INTO dest (v) 
    SELECT POW(v, 2) AS p FROM source 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE dest.v=POW(v, 2);
```

(Untested...)

Comment: So `POW(v, 2)` isn't evaluated in the SELECT clause if the key exists in `dest`?

Comment: It is evaluated, only the assigned alias is not available for use. That we can call a improvement point for MySQL. You will run into this in more cases (sad enough). Maybe the MariaDB project will handle this sort of improvements quicker (wait and see)